# Upload images asp.net MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an mvc 5 application in which a product has one or many images.in the create form, i want to upload images for product before save it.

I'm trying to use a temp folder to save images and once a product is saved, we save images in database, but i don't think it's the best solution

```
public ActionResult ProductPictureAdd(int pictureId, int productId)
    {
        if (pictureId == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        var product = _productService.GetById(productId);
        if (product == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("No product found with the specified id");


        if (_workContext.CurrentUser != null && product.UserId != _workContext.CurrentUser.ID)
            return RedirectToAction("List");

        _productService.InsertProductPicture(new ProductPicture
        {
            PictureId = pictureId,
            ProductId = productId,
            CreatedOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
            UpdatedOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow
        });



        return Json(new { Result = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I'm looking for a better solution

Comment: @CalebB is asking you to be more detailed in the description of your problem (source code would help) and to be more specific in what problem you are encountering.

Comment: ah ok, sorry, i have added the source code for uploading one picture at time , actually user can't upload images for a new product, he can upload images from the "edit product" view

Comment: Please explain "i want to upload images for product before save it". If the file upload fields are in the same form, they'll be posted along with the other information for the product. By the time you could save the image, you could already save the product. What is it that you're actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do it but one sentence caught my attention:

> i want to upload images for product before save it

This means for me that you should use AJAX to upload the images. I explain how to do it in this article I wrote a while ago: http://davidsonsousa.net/en/post/how-to-upload-a-file-using-mvc-3-and-ajax

> we save images in database, but i don't think it's the best solution

It depends on what exactly you want. I normally save the images into `App_Data` and then create a handler to get them. But I would save them into the database without any problem in case I would not be able to save them in any folder due project restrictions.